# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page path

Tags: java, spring-mvc

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/jsp/admissionForm.jsp at line 33

Getting error on line 33. I'm new to Spring MVC and cannot figured out this error
:

```html
30:   <table>
31:    <tr>
32:     <td>Customer Name :</td>
33:     <td><form:input path="studentName" /></td>
34:     <td><form:errors path="studentName" cssClass="error" /></td>
35:    </tr>
36:    <tr>
```

Model Class

```
@Entity
public class Student {

    @NotEmpty
    private String studentName;

    @Size(min=2,max=43)
    private String major;

    private Long studentMobile;
    private Date studentDOB;
    private ArrayList<String> studentSkills;
    private Address studentAddress;
}
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admissionForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView addmissionForm(){
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("admissionForm");
    return mv;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/submitAdmissionForm" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView submitAdmissionForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("student1") Student student1, BindingResult result){

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        ModelAndView model1 = new ModelAndView("admissionForm");
        return model1;
    }

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("admissionSuccess");
    return mv;
}
```

JSP

```
<h2> SignUp Form - JSR303 @Valid example</h2>

<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="student1" action="/submitAdmissionForm">
    <form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div" />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Customer Name :</td>
            <td><form:input path="studentName" /></td>
            <td><form:errors path="studentName" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Customer Age :</td>
            <td><form:input path="major" /></td>
            <td><form:errors path="major" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```